# Unit Test Project and MySql Odbc Driver (Visual Studio Community 2013)

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I created **Unit Test Project** in **Visual Studio Community 2013**. 
I connect to MySql Database via MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver.
When I run Unit Test Project as Console Application (exe), I connect to db succesufuly.
But when I run Unit Test from Visual Studio, error occured.

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft] [ ... ODBC ] 'National language message'

I installed mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.3.msi from Oracle, I connect to MySql from VisualStudio-ServerExplorer- DataConnection - MySql succesfully.

I try build Test Project as 32-bit,64-bit, but Test from Vs doesn`t work.

Answer (score 0):

Self answering :-):

I have installed only 64-bit ODBC driver (see at c:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 5.1). When I installed 32-bit ODBC driver (see at ODBC driver c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector ODBC 5.1), UnitTestProject connect to MySql successfully.